# I can't build Spring Boot app mvn package

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar

I created Java Spring Boot REST API. I can run Spring Boot API from **Springtoolsuit4** working, and I can connect localhost, which is returning a JSON value.

In this API I have use external jar file put inside and create instance from that jar file then I run terminal `mvn package`. It's showing:

[image]

But I can run from Springtoolsuit now I want to deploy to server; that's why I need to build executable jar file

The issue is external jar file class cannot build

```
import com.dbs.sgqr.generator.QRGenerator;
import com.dbs.sgqr.generator.QRGeneratorImpl;
import com.dbs.sgqr.generator.io.PayNow;
import com.dbs.sgqr.generator.io.QRDimensions;
import com.dbs.sgqr.generator.io.QRGeneratorResponse;
import com.dbs.sgqr.generator.io.QRType;
```

My pom file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.propnex</groupId>
<artifactId>DbsQr</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>DbsQr</name>
<description>Project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.dbs.sgqr.generator</groupId>
        <artifactId>SGQRGeneratorV1.5</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
      <systemPath>${project.basedir}/SGQRGeneratorV1.5.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Paste the error in the question as text using the code formatting tool

Comment: You have to add `<dependency>` tag in your `pom.xml`.

Comment: which one i need add pom file give me some sample

Comment: You need to show your `pom.xml` as well

Comment: now i added my pom file also please check

Comment: The pom.xml which you have put in here are all standard libraries which will not contain the classes which start with com.dbs.* which looks like a library from DBS bank.

Comment: Did you add any jar manually to build path instead of specifying in pom?

Comment: Yeah I added in classpath need specify pom file also? Give me some examples

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.